# Getting work queue and RPC to work together

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm starting to use RabbitMQ and after following along with the tutorials, I'm now trying to get it to work the way I need it to and I'm running into difficulty. The setup I have is that I need to be able to make a RPC first, and then based on the response from that the client will (or will not) send another message to a work queue (where I don't need a response to the client). Unfortunately, my efforts to get this to work together doesn't seem to be working out the way I want. On the server side, I have something like this (I've tried many variations all with the same problems):

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
connection = factory.CreateConnection();
channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "jobs", type: "direct", durable: true);

// I started with a named queue, not sure if that's better or worse for this
var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, 
    exchange: "jobs",
    routingKey: "saveJob_queue");

channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    // save stuff that was sent with the saveJob_queue routingKey
}

channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, 
    noAck: false,
    consumer: consumer);

// set up channel for RPC
// Not sure if this has to have another channel, but it wasn't working on the same channel either
rpcChannel = connection.CreateModel();
var rpcQueueName = rpcChannel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

rpcChannel.QueueBind(queue: rpcQueueName,  
    exchange: "jobs",
    routingKey: "rpc_CheckJob_queue");

var rpcConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(rpcChannel);

rpcConsumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    // do my remote call and send back a response
}
```

The problem I have is that a message sent to the `jobs` exchange with the routing key `rpc_CheckJob_queue` still ends up triggering the `Recieved` event on the first channel despite the fact that it should only receive `saveJob_queue` routes. I could check `ea.RoutingKey` in that handler and just ignore those messages, but I don't understand how and why they end up there in the first place?

What would be the correct way to set a connection so it can receive both work queue messages and RPC messages and handle them correctly?

Comment: Are you missing something like `rpcChannel .BasicConsume(rpcQueueName: queueName,` ? Also if you could post your code for sending the messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I gave up on this and decided to just filter in the `Received` event. I think the problem is that RabbitMQ only has a `Received` event on a *channel*, but not on a *queue*. So the `Received` event gets hit either way. So now I have this:

```
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,  
         durable: true,
         exclusive: false,
         autoDelete: false,
         arguments: null);

channel.QueueDeclare(queue: rpcQueueName,
         durable: false,
         exclusive: false,
         autoDelete: false,
         arguments: null);

channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    switch (ea.RoutingKey)
    {
        case queueName:
            SaveJob(ea);
            break;
        case rpcQueueName:
            CheckJob(ea);
            break;
    }
    channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
};

channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, 
    noAck: false,
    consumer: consumer);

channel.BasicConsume(queue: rpcQueueName,
                     noAck: false,
                     consumer: consumer);
```

I'm open to better suggestions since this seems a bit off.

So sending is just:

```
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.Persistent = true;

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                     routingKey: queueName,
                     basicProperties: properties,
                     body: body);
```

for the regular work job and:

```
var corrId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
props.ReplyTo = replyQueueName;
props.CorrelationId = corrId;

var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                     routingKey: rpcQueueName,
                     basicProperties: props,
                     body: messageBytes);

while (true)   
{
    var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
    if (ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId == corrId)
    {
        return ea.Body != null && ea.Body.Any() ? BitConverter.ToInt32(ea.Body,0) : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

For RPC.

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't specifying a name for your queue I suspect you are getting the same queue twice. So I think what is happening is essentially this.

jobs --> saveJob_queue --> SomeSystemQueue 
jobs --> rpc_CheckJob_queue--> SomeSystemQueue

Try picking two separate queue names, and then running your code again.
So instead of this:

```
var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, 
    exchange: "jobs",
    routingKey: "saveJob_queue");
```

have:

```
var name = "Queue A";
channel.QueueDeclare(name);
channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName, 
        exchange: "jobs",
        routingKey: "saveJob_queue");
```

Then name your second queue something else and try that.

Comment: I originally did have the two queues named (differently, of course), but had the same problem.

Comment: OK. You might want to switch back to that, just to completely rule that out. Could you post your sending logic as well? Just so everyone can see which routing key you are addressing and so on.